# Calling another observable with the response of another in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I am writing an Angular 4 application using `HttpClient` that displays movie show times. There are 2 JSON files where the data is located: `showtimes.json` and `movies.json`.

```
// showtimes.json    
[{
"id": "2030c64ce72b4e4605cb01f2ba405b7d",
"name": "Arclight", // need to display this information
"showtimes": {
  "b4c2c326a4d335da654d4fd944bf88d0": [ // need to use this id
      "11:30 pm", "2:45 pm", "8:35 pm", "4:15 pm", "10:30 pm"
  ]
 } 
}]

// movies.json
[{
"b4c2c326a4d335da654d4fd944bf88d0": { // to retrieve the title, rating, and poster
  "title": "Fifty Shades Darker", // needs to be displayed
  "rating": "R", // needs to be displayed
  "poster": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dt6wgt92cu9wqcr/fifty_shades_darker.jpg" // needs to be displayed
}
}]
```

I have service that can retrieve the `title` and `name` of the theater. But now I must use the value in the `showtimes` object to display the correct title name. As you see `b4c2c326a4d335da654d4fd944bf88d0` is the id of the movie title and can be retrieved from the `movies.json` file.

So far this is my component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._moviesDataService.getShowtimes()
  .subscribe(res => this.results = res)
}
```

And this is my service.

```
getShowtimes (): Observable<ShowTimes> {
  return this._http.get<ShowTimes>(this._showtimesURL)
}
```

My question is how do I retrieve the `title` of the movie using its id? Would this require two chained Observables? Would I need to loop through the movies array and `.filter` it?

I've included an example of what I am trying to build [image: Example]

Comment: Yes, you will need to combine observables. Look into e.g. `forkJoin` and the various `map` methods.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually, when you have one Observable and you need to grab something from . it and return a different Observable, you can use `switchMap`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._moviesDataService.getShowtimes()
        .switchMap(res => { 
            const id = Object.keys(res[0].showtimes)[0]; // assuming you have one element in your array and you want the first id from showtimes
            return this.getMovies(id); // assuming, you have a separate method that returns the movies
        })
        .subscribe(res => this.results = res)
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since you need results of both Observable but also you need the results of the first to request the second here's an idea how you can do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._moviesDataService.getShowtimes()
        .switchMap(res => { 
            const showtimes = res[0].showtimes;
            const id = Object.keys(showtimes)[0];

            return Observable.zip(
                this.getMovies(id),
                Observable.of(showtimes[id])
            );
        })
        .subscribe(([movies, showtimes]) => {
            this.results.movies = movies; // or assign it to some other property
            this.results.showtimes = showtimes; // and use in the template
        }
```

Comment: No, forkJoin takes several requests and returns the responses as an array, you can&#39;t send one request based on the data received from another, you need a switchMap (or a mergeMap)

Comment: I actually need to display the data from `getShowtimes()` and then pass in the `showtimes` object to retrieve the titles from `getMovies().` When I iterate through `this.results`, only the data from `getMovies()` is there. Is there a way to send the data from the first call to the front end and also perform another Observable with `switchMap()`?

Comment: can you update your post with the desired output (what you want `this.results` to equal to)? it's hard to understand what exactly you need to do.

Comment: Awesome! Got both responses that I need!

Comment: Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I think because you need to retrieve titles of all the movies, you have to chain the array of IDs in the first request's response, into a series of requests for movies' titles. something like this: (assuming you have a method like `getMovieTitle` that gets data of a movie based on it's id and it returns an observable)

```
this._moviesDataService.getShowtimes()
        .switchMap(res => { 
            let resArray: any[] = res.map(
                    item=>this._moviesDataService.getMovieTitle(
                        Object.keys(item.showtimes)[0]
            ))
            return Observable.merge(...resArray);
        })
        .subscribe(res => /*you will get a new res for each movie title here*/)
```

what [`Observable.merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) does, is it `Turn multiple observables into a single observable.` so you will get all the results in one subscription.

**Note:**
don't forget to assign all of this to a `subscription` and unsubscribe it at `ngOnDestroy` of the component (to prevent memory leak)

Comment: I actually need to display the data from `getShowtimes()` and then pass in the `showtimes` object to retrieve the titles from `getMovies().` When I iterate through `this.results`, only the data from `getMovies()` is there. Is there a way to send the data from the first call to the front end and also perform another Observable with `switchMap()`?